unique shortest paths form a tree
I'm reading some material about shortest paths of a graph.
And I confronted a simple statement ;

It’s not hard to see that if shortest paths are unique, then they form a tree,
because any subpath of a shortest path is itself a shortest path.

I thought I've understood it all, but now I'm not certain.
I can accept the fact that any subpath of a shortest path is itself a shortest path.
Let $p$ be a shortest path from $a$ to $b$.
Suppose that $p$ also passes through $c$.
Write $p=(a, \cdots, c, \cdots, b)$ and $p=p_1\cup p_2$ where $p_1=(a,\cdots,c)$ and $p_2=(c,\cdots,b)$.
If $q_1(\ne p_1)$ is the shortest path from $a$ to $c$ so that $d(q_1)<d(p_1)$ where $d(\cdot)$ maps paths to the distance of it, then $q_1\cup p_2$ is shorter than $p$.
But how can I see that shortest paths form a tree provided that shortest paths are unique?
More formally, consider a directed weighted graph $G=(V,E, W)$ and fix a vertex $v\in V$.
For any $u(\ne v)\in V$, there exists a unique shortest path $p(v,u)$ from $v$ to $u$.
Then I have to prove that
$$\bigcup_{u\in V, u\ne v}p(v,u)$$
is a tree.
By the union of graphs, I mean graph union : $(V_1, E_1)\cup(V_1, E_1) = (V_1\cup V_2, E_1\cup E_2)$.
Note that a path can be thought of as a graph.
By a tree, I mean a graph where any two vertices are connected by exactly one path.

Suppose you have a cycle. Show that there are two paths intersecting at some vertex ($\neq v$) such that none is a subpath of the other. Find a contradiction.

I asked essentially the same question and received an answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4971093/union-of-shortest-paths-from-a-given-vertex-form-a-tree

@JLGL Thanks. But your case is for undirected graphs, while I'm dealing with an directed case.

@govindah you say you $G$ is an undirected graph in your question.

@caduk Sorry for a late reply. Suppose that I have a cycle $(u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4)$ and suppose that there is a path $p(v,u_1)$ from $u$ to to $u_1$. What is your some vertex where two distinct paths intersect?

@Nic Sorry. I have to talk about 'directed graph'. Now I changed the word. A big mistake.

Let $G=(V={(v,w)},E={(v,w),(w,v)}$. Then obviously $v\to w$ and $w\to v$ are the shortest paths in this graph. Now tell me, is $G$ a tree?

@ConnFus No $G$ is not a tree ; $E$ itself forms a cycle. But see the above question again. I fixed a vertex $v$ and union all the paths from $v$. So $(w,v)$ can not be included in my union.

Ahh, I see. Which definition for a tree do you use?

@ConnFus I was reading this material, the second paragraph of 8.1. This book seems to have no tree definition for directed graph, but it writes : "Directed graphs require slightly different definitions. A directed walk is a sequence of vertices $v_0\rightarrow v_1\rightarrow \cdots\rightarrow v_l$ such that $v_{i-1}\rightarrow v_i$ is a directed edge for every index $i$. (omit) A directed graph is acyclic if it doesn't contain a directed cycle; directed acyclic graphs are often called dags"

@ConnFus So it seems that trees are dags. The book is "Algorithms" by Jeff Erickson.

Hmm, thats not really a definition you want for a "directed tree". The path uniqueness is characterizing for trees. I think they actually speak of rooted trees (see wiki, no clue how you did that link). So for now you need to find out what exactly characterizes a rooted tree, so we know what property it is we actually have to show for $\bigcup_{u\in V, u\ne v}p(v,u)$

Yeah so it is enough to show that the union has no cycles or any two nodes in the union can not be joined by distinct paths. I tried many examples to conclude successfully to a (rooted) tree. It should be a tree as the examples seems. But I don't know how to prove that this is a tree.

@tkw Thanks a lot. But are you ConnFus?

@govindah i'm not! but their answer looks like it covers my ideas. (my definition doesn't imply trees are connected, but that's also true in your example.)

@tkw Can I please see your answer?

@govindah I decided I didn't like the definition I suggested so I deleted my earlier comment — see my answer below

So we have to show that the shortest path graph (SPG) has the following properties:
(1) There's a single vertex from which all edges are reachable
(2) No vertex has two incoming edges
(3) There exists no cycle.
Condition (1) is the root in the rooted tree. It also guarantees that the graph is connected. Condition (2) means there are no two distinct paths to a single vertex, because at some point they'd have to merge, and this vertex then would have two incoming edges.
That SPG has property (1) is easy to see by construction.
For property (2) assume a vertex $w$ has two incoming edges. This can only have happened because we had two shortest paths to two vertices $w',w''$, which intersect in $w$. But then we'd have two distinct paths to $w$ which both are shortest, which isn't possible per our assumptions. (Note that we used here that every sub-path of a shortest path is also a shortest path)
Now for (3): If there were a cycle and it wouldn't contain $v$, then the cycle would be reachable from $v$, so one vertex would have two incoming edges. So any cycle would need to contain $v$. Now if any cycle which contains $v$ has non-positive weight, then we can repeat it as often as we want, and use it as prefix of any shortest path. So in this case there would exist no shortest path between any two vertices, which, once again, goes against the assumption that there exist (unique) shortest paths.
That leaves us with the possibility of a cycle containing $v$ with positive weight. The reasoning here is similar to (1): If we had such a cycle which contains $v$, then it means there exists a shortest path (starting from $v$) which goes through $v$. But such a path contains a cycle, which as previously concluded has positive weight, so just skipping the cycle would lower the weight of the path, which is a contradiction to the assumption that it's a shortest path.

Yeah (1) is true from the construction. The single can be $v$ where $v$ is the fixed vertex. But what does (2) mean? Does it mean that the union (SPG) has no vertex $u$ such that (a) there exist at least two paths joining from $v$ to $u$? or such that (b) there exist at least two edges $(u, u_1)$ and $u, u_2$?

It means that there exists no vertex $u$ which has two distinct edges $(w,u)$ and $(w',u)$. This then further implies (a)

A graph $G=\left(V={v,u_1,u_2},E={(v,u_1),(v,u_2),(u_1, u_2)}\right)$ with weights(distances) $W(v,u_1)=2$, $W(v,u_2)=3$ and $W(u_1,u_2)=4$ has two shortest paths $(v, u_1)$ and $(v,u_2)$ with shortest distances $2$ and $3$. That is $(v,u_1,u_2)$ can also be a path from $v$ to $u_2$, but it is not shorter than $(v,u_2)$. Then the the union $H$ of the paths is $H=\left(V={v,u_1,u_2},E'={(v,u_1),(v,u_2)}\right)$ and $H$ is a directed tree. But $H$ violates your condition (2).

In your example $v$ has two outgoing edges, but no incoming edges. Both $u_1$ and $u_2$ have each exactly one incoming edge. So there is no vertex with two incoming edges in $H$, so it fulfills property (2).

Sorry for my confusion. You're right. You were talking about incoming edges while I talked about outgoing ones.

I understand until the first case of (3) when the cycle doesn't contain $v$. Thanks for your delicate reasoning. But sorry for my inaccurate question but I wanted the case when the weights are all nonnegative. Also, I think your reasoning is not valid if weights are all nonnegative. I know that if weights of the cycle sum to negative, then we can't find the shortest path. But the contradiction can occur only when the weights of the cycle sum to negative, isn't it?

I'm not 100% sure what you want to say, but I think this is just phrasing. We say "a cycle has negative weight" if the sum of its edge weights is negative. Because a cycle is a special path, and for path we also say its weight is the sum of its edges.

I mean the following: You said if any cycle which contains $v$ has negative weight, then ~. Since the dependent clause is established only under the condition of the if clause (negative weight cycle), you didn't discuss the case where it's not the condition of the if clause (nonnegative weight cycle).

But I think we can exclude the case when the cycle contains $v$. If the cycle contains $v$, then $v$ is an outgoing vertex of an edge, which can not happen.

Ah, since (2) allows one incoming edge into v. You're right, we need to handle this one as well. You're also right in that it can not happen, but we must indeed prove it

Thank you for your answer. Have a nice day!

I'm going to use the following definition of "tree" (perhaps better seen as "rooted directed tree" or something like that):

A rooted tree is a directed graph $T$ and a $v \in T$, such that every vertex $u \in T$ is connected to $v$ by exactly one path.

Let $$G_{SP}(v) = \bigcup_{u\in V, u\ne v}p(v,u), $$ be the shortest path graph as you define. We will prove that, for every $u$, the only path from $v$ to $u$ in $G_{SP}(v)$ is the shortest path $p(v,u)$. Let $v = a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n=u$ be any path and proceed by induction on $n$. If $n\le 1$ then it's clear.
For $n>1$, the edge $a_{n-1} \to a_n = u$ must belong to $p(v,u')$ for some $u'$. Suppose this path is
$$ v \to b_1 \to \dots \to b_m = a_{n-1} \to b_{m+1} = u \to \dots \to u'. $$
Since subpaths of a shortest path are shortest paths, the sequence $v,b_1,\dots,b_m,u$ must be $p(v,u)$, and by induction the paths $v,b_1,\dots,b_m=a_{n-1}$ and $v,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ must be the same (they must both be $p(v,a_{n-1})$. But then we know that $a_i = b_i$ for every $1\le i\le n$, so we must have $a_0,\dots,a_n = p(v,u)$, as required.
I don't think the definition I gave in the comment was satisfactory, but I think this answers your question :-).
Edit: my definition is called an "arborescence" in the literature, which is way catchier. In particular, note that the underlying undirected graph is a tree.

How can you justify the following sentence ; "For $n>1$, the edge $a_{n-1}\to a_n=u$' must belong to $p(v,u')$ for some $u'$?" Can I simply choose $u'=u$? It make senses but it's meaningless

I love your problem formation. It seems like we barely have nothing to prove. "From $v$ to $u$, there is the unique shortest path and we're going to prove that there is just one path each." What should we prove?

The proof shows that, yes, you can choose $u=u’$, but you don’t know that to start off with. The sentence you quote follows from the definition of the graph $G_{SP}(v)$ — since the graph is the union of all the shortest paths, every edge must lie in some shortest path.

Question Formulation Again
Let $G=(V, E, W)$ be a directed weighted graph where $W:E\to\mathbb R$ and $W(e)\ge0$ for all $e\in E$.
Fix a vertex $v\in V$.
For any $u(\ne v)\in V$, there exists a unique shortest path $p(v,u)$ from $v$ to $u$.
Prove that
$$H=\bigcup_{u\in V, u\ne v}p(v,u)$$
is a directed tree or a graph which is connected and acyclic (contains no cycles).

Notations and Definitions
Since $G$ is a directed graph, denote an edge $e\in E$ by a ordered pair $e=(v_1,v_2)$ where $v_1,v_2\in V$.
Denote a path by an enumeration of vertices by parentheses ; $(v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n)$ is a path where $v_i\in V$.
Note that an edge can also be thought of as a path.
Define a (noncommuative) binary operation '$\cup$' on a pair of paths by $(v_1,\cdots,v_n)\cup(v_n,\cdots,v_m)=(v_1,\cdots,v_n\cdots,v_m)$.
So $p_1\cup p_2$ can only be defined only when the end vertex of $p_1$ corresponds with the start vetex of $p_2$.
But, in the definition of $H$ above, the union is a graph union $(V_1, E_1)\cup(V_1, E_1) = (V_1\cup V_2, E_1\cup E_2)$ ; we can view a path as a subgraph of $G$.
As mentioned earlier, $p(v,u)$ is the unique shortest path from $v$ to $u$.
If $u=v$, take $p(u,v)=\emptyset$ or an empty parentheses.
By a predecessor I mean the following.
If $p(v,u)=(v,u_1,u_2,\cdots, u_n, u)$, then the predecessor of $u$ is $\text{pred}(u)=u_n$.
By the definition of the predecessor, $\text{pred}(u)$ is uniquely defined for every vertex $u(\ne v)\in V$.

My answer (edited version from ConnFus' answer)
(1) Every vertex $u\in V$ can be joined by the shortest path from $v$ to $u$.
(2) $p(v,u) = p(v,\text{pred}(u))\cup(\text{pred}(u), u)$
(3) There is no cycle in $H$.

Proof
(1) is clearly true from the hypothesis.
This proves that $H$ is connected.
(2) Using the above notation $p(v,u) = (v, u_1, u_2,\cdots,u_n,u)$ and $\text{pred}(u)=u_n$, it holds that $p(v,u) = (v, u_1, u_2,\cdots,u_n)\cup(u_n,u)$.
It follows from 'any subpath of a shortest path is itself a shortest path' that $p(v,u) = p(v,\text{pred}(u))\cup(\text{pred}(u), u)$
(3) Suppose that $H$ has a cycle $C=[c_1,\cdots,c_m]$ so that $\text{pred}(c_{i+1})=c_i$ for $1\le i\le m-1$ and $\text{pred}(c_1)=c_m$.
Suppose first that $v\in C$, say, $v=c_m$.
Repeated uses of (2) imply the following contradiction ;
\begin{align*}
\emptyset
&=p(v,c_m)\\
&=p(v,c_{m-1})\cup(c_{m-1},c_m)\\
&=p(v,c_{m-2})\cup(c_{m-2},c_{m-1})\cup(c_{m-1},c_m)\\
&=p(v,c_1)\cup(c_1,c_2)\cdots\cup(c_{m-1},c_m)\\
&=(v,c_1)\cup(c_1,c_2)\cdots\cup(c_{m-1},c_m)
\end{align*}
Suppose second that $v\not\in C$.
Fix $c_i$ in $C$ and let $p(v,c_i)=(v,u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_l,c_i)$.
Let $J$ be the smallest $j$ such that $u_j\in C$ so that $u_{J-1}\not\in C$.
Write $u_J=c_I$.
Then $u_J$ has two distinct predecessors $u_{J-1}$ and $c_{I-1}$ which contradicts the uniqueness of the $\text{pred}(u_J)$.
Now, by (3), $H$ is acyclic.
Thus, $H$ is a directed tree.
