Union of shortest paths from a given vertex form a tree
I am having some trouble with the following (simple) problem:

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph with positive edge weights. Let $u \in V(G)$ and denote $P_{v}$ for the shortest path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$. Prove that $T = \bigcup_{v \in V(G)} P_{v}$ is a tree.

By a tree I mean a connected acyclic graph. I understand why $T$ is connected, but I'm having trouble proving acyclicity. Suppose that $T$ has a cycle $C$ and consider $v \in C$. My idea was that there is a path $P' \neq P_{v}$ from $u$ to $v$ that goes through the cycle. This path $P'$ may be shorter or longer than $P_{v}$ depending on the weights on the edge. If $P'$ is a shorter path (that is, it has smaller weight), then this contradicts the fact that $P_{v}$ is the shortest path from $u$ to $v$. If $P'$ is a longer path (that is, it has larger weight) then it is part of the union $T$, which is a contradiction since it isn't the longest path from $u$ to the vertex $v$.
I am not sure whether this is correct, any help is appreciated.

"the shortest" is misleading.  Consider a square with unit edge weights.  From any vertex, there are two minimal paths along two edges to the non-adjacent vertex.  To address the "more complicated in a real graph" version of this, you need to select from each vertex's "minimal paths" the one that it and all longer paths through that vertex to further out vertices will use.

Thank you, my doubts were with the square and similar cases. But I’m not quite sure I understand your other point. What would dictate the choice between the two minimal paths from one corner node to the non-adjacent node in the square you mentioned?

Hang a fifth vertex off the diagonally opposite vertex.  If you take one path around the square to the diagonally opposite vertex and the other path around the square to the fifth vertex, the union of those two paths contains the entire square.  To avoid this, since the two paths to the diagonally opposite vertex have the same length, pick one and all paths through the diagonally opposite vertex must use that one choice as their initial segment.

Thank you! So a similar approach is needed when a vertex $v$ has two or more minimal paths from $u$. In the case that all shortest paths are unique, is my previous reasoning correct?

Yes, if you extend your argument to handle all three cases of trichotomy: $P' < P_v$, $P' > P_V$, and (what we've been talking about in comments) $P' = P_v$.  The two cases you have are fine.
$$ \qquad $$
However, the problem as stated is a little defective: generally, minimal paths need not be unique, so this choice process is needed to keep that union of minimal paths acyclic.
